# Chart.js process data in server-side before show to chart

Tags: javascript, php, data-structures, chart.js, laravel-8

i want to process generated Eloquent result data in server side before show it to Chart.js, all the data are dynamically generated from databases.

I've facing some issue while try to increment `subtotal` values for the same `items_name` and `sales_date` and then show labels, x & y axis from database.

Here's my Eloquent `->toArray()` response :

```php
array:5 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "sales_date" => "2021-02-25"
    "subtotal" => 800000
    "items_name" => "Kitchen Set"
  ],
  1 => array:3 [
    "sales_date" => "2021-02-25"
    "subtotal" => 2000000
    "items_name" => "Kitchen Set"
  ],
  2 => array:3 [
    "sales_date" => "2021-02-26"
    "subtotal" => 1000000
    "items_name" => "Chair"
  ],
  3 => array:3 [
    "sales_date" => "2021-02-26"
    "subtotal" => 1000000
    "items_name" => "Chair"
  ],
  4 => array:3 [
    "sales_date" => "2021-02-27"
    "subtotal" => 1000000
    "items_name" => "Stove"
  ],
]
```

I also tried to use `->map()` function in server side :

```php
$processed['labels']  =   [];

$results->map( function( $val, $key ) use(&$processed) {
    $processed['labels'][$key]  =   $val->sales_date;

    if( $processed['labels'][$key] === $val->sales_date) {
        $processed['datas'][$key]   =   ["data" => $val->subtotal, "label" => $val->varieties_name];
    }
});
```

but i confused about the required data structure for Chart.js and show "0" sales like Google Analytics chart if there's no visitor like this image below :

[image: Analytics chart]

Here's some expected result in Chart.js (the `x axis` should same from the datasets) :

[image]

This is my hardcoded Chart.js

```js
$.ajax({
    url     :   "{{ route('home.selling') }}",
    type    :   "GET",
    success :   function( res ){
        var selling_chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("selling_per_items"), {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['2021-02-24', '2021-02-25', '2021-02-26', '2021-02-27'],
                datasets: [{
                    data   : [ '2800000' ],
                    label  : 'Kitchen Set',
                    lineTension: 0,
                    fill   : false,
                    borderColor  : dynamicColors(),
                },{
                    data   : [ '2000000' ],
                    label  : 'Chair',
                    lineTension: 0,
                    fill   : false,
                    borderColor  : dynamicColors(),
                },{
                    data   : [ '100000' ],
                    label  : 'Stove',
                    lineTension: 0,
                    fill   : false,
                    borderColor  : dynamicColors(),
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio : false,
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        });
    }

});
```

My environment :

```
jQuery : v3.4.1
Chart.js : v2.8.0
Laravel : 8.x
```

Thank You